# Output the data from MySQL into an 2 dimensional Array

Tags: php, mysql

I have record rows in MySQL as

```
id=0     name=tom  grade=A

id=1     name=jeff grade=B

id=2     name=lisa grade=B
```

....... etc

Now I want to output that do a 2 dimensional array 
such as

```
content{
{id=0
 name=tom
 grade=A
}

{id=1
name=jeff
grade=B}

{id=2
name=lisa
grade=B}}

$query="SELECT * FROM `user`";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$grades=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  ...........
}
```

***What I should put into the while loop?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_fetch_assoc returns a associative array with the col name as the key and the value as the value. You have almost got everything you need to put this in another array how you want. Just put the following code in the loop to append the assoc arrays from each row into the $grades array:

```
$grades[] = $row;
```

Then you can access the values of the grades array like so:

```
$grades[1]['grade'] //returns the grade of row 1
```

Comment: if I do like your way and I echo $grades; it only output the word Array. I want to be able to output all the data out like such {id=0
 name=tom
 grade=A
}

{id=1
name=jeff
grade=B}

{id=2
name=lisa
grade=B}}

Comment: It prints the words 'Array' because it is an object that can not just be echoed to the screen. You can print the contents of the array using the print_r function. Eg. `print_r($grades)`

Comment: How do I output the $grades array to a JSON output such as  Content:[{{id=0
 name=tom
 grade=A
}

{id=1
name=jeff
grade=B}

{id=2
name=lisa
grade=B} Status:'OK'}   I don't think print_r would work.

Comment: Ok, that's fine But I need one more step.    I need put that grades into another array.      $grades=json_encode($grades);   $output=array('status'=>'OK', 'content' => $grades);   Now I want to output that output array. SHould I do $output=  json_encodes($output)?  and then echo $output

Comment: Yeah, that should work fine. Make sure you use just json_encode though (no 's').

Comment: If I do that, 2 json_encodes     first json_encodes($grades) then json_encodes($output) the result has /  such as {"status":1,"content":"{\"tom\":\"A\",\"jeff\":\"B\",\"lisa\":\"B\"}"}